# Need Decrypt method in node js for below c# encryption method

Tags: c#, node.js, cryptography

I have this c# code to encrypt data, need a decryption method in node.js. I tried the crypto module of node.js but was not able to proceed.

```
private string Encrypt(string clearText)
{
    string EncryptionKey = "Something";
    byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
    using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
    return clearText;
}
```

I have tried in crypto module

```
cryptogrphy.pbkdf2("Something", 'Ivan Medvedev', 1000, 128/4, function (cErr, cBuffer) { 
    var cKey = cBuffer.slice(0, 32);
    var cIV = cBuffer.slice(0, 16);
    var cDecipher = cryptogrphy.createDecipheriv("AES-128-CBC", cKey, cIV);
    var sDecoded = cDecipher.update(text);
    sDecoded += cDecipher.final("utf8");
    console.log(sDecoded);
}); //'Ivan Medvedev' is equivalent string to salt byte in encryption method
```

Comment: If needed I can provide decryption method written in c#

Answer (score 0):

There are all sorts of problems with your node.js code (AES-128 vs. AES-256, IV is part of the key, mixed encoding of decrypted text).

```
cryptogrphy.pbkdf2("Something", 'Ivan Medvedev', 1000, 32+16, 'sha1', function (cErr, cBuffer) { 
    var cKey = cBuffer.slice(0, 32);
    var cIV = cBuffer.slice(32);
    var cDecipher = cryptogrphy.createDecipheriv("AES-256-CBC", cKey, cIV);
    var sDecoded = cDecipher.update(text, 'binary', 'utf8');
    sDecoded += cDecipher.final("utf8");
    console.log(sDecoded);
});
```

Comment: It's not clear what `text` is, so I assumed it is a Latin1-encoded ciphertext string.

Comment: get exception Invalid IV length

Comment: Sorry about that. I've mixed up bits and bytes myself